# How to change "max_kv_size_per_doc"?

Tags: docker, mapreduce, nosql, couchbase

I need to change this parameter. Default is 1048576 bytes. I want at least 2097152 bytes.
I already know this is not recommended for a production environment as I have already read in this forum.

I'm using Couchbase 4.5 with Docker.

I already changed the file "opt/couchbase/etc/couchdb/default.ini" and restarted the container and later the service inside the container. But it doesn't take effect.

I also tried this:
curl -X POST http://Administrator:password@localhost:8091/diag/eval -d 'rpc:eval_everywhere(erlang, apply, [fun() -> couch_config:set("mapreduce", "max_kv_size_per_doc", "2097152") end, []]).'

But with no success.

During my tests, I changed the file "opt/couchbase/etc/couchdb/default.ini" to set a new value for the parameter "function_timeout" and it worked. I tested with a sleep inside map function and the log showed timeout error.

It means that when I restart Couchbase it takes the new configuration.
But change the parameter "max_kv_size_per_doc" makes no difference. Does anyone know why?

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Angelo

Comment: if this is with docker, can you show a reproducer, at least your Dockerfile and your `docker run` command?

Comment: I'm using https://hub.docker.com/r/couchbase/server/ with tag "4.5.0-beta"

Comment: Ok, and can you show your `docker run` command?

Comment: docker run -d -p 8091:8091 -p 8092:8092 -p 8093:8093 -p 11210:11210 --net=host --ulimit nofile=40960:40960 --ulimit core=100000000:100000000 --ulimit memlock=100000000:100000000 --name cbts -v /mnt/hdd/couchbase:/opt/couchbase/var couchbase/server:4.5.0-beta

Comment: Did you `docker commit -t mytag` and then start the committed image?

Comment: No, but I'm sure this is not the problem. I have a Couchbase container working. I changed the parameter for timeout, restarted it and it takes effect. The problem is with max_kv_size parameter

Comment: Could you solve this problem?!

Comment: Unfortunately not